# KMM- Is it possible to add a web module to a KMM app and use the same shared library?

Tags: android, ios, gradle, web, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a KMM app. Runs smoothly on each native side (ANDROID and IOS). I'm currently trying to add a Web module.

To do so, I added the web compose module through IntelliJ.

First I added it outside the shared library, but it couldn't manage to use the shared dependency and the module I added there for it.

-App
-shared

- androidmain
- commonMain
- iosMain
- jsMain
  -webApp

Then I tried adding the web module inside the shared library, but again the commonMain seems unreachable. Plus in this case the navigator could not even load the UI elements that were in the Main.kt.

-App
-shared

- androidmain
- commonMain
- iosMain
- webMain

Did someone already deal with this ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a sample project called People in Space, created by a GDE John O'Reilly. This should give you an example of everything you need.

https://github.com/joreilly/PeopleInSpace

Comment: Thanks @Chris Ill check that.